# If else function

Tags: python

I have two objects "ObjectA" and "ObjectB". Object A when selected extrudes up in the z direction. Object B when selected extrudes down in the z direction.

Currently I have two different buttons each having their own script. One for A the other for B.

I would like to have one button. So this is where I need a script and it gets tricky. If Object A is selected, it will run the script, else it does nothing. If object B is selected it runs the script, else it does nothing.

I hope I am descriptive enough..

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy

ObjectA=bpy.data.objects['Cube']
ObjectB=bpy.data.objects['Cone']

class ObjectAOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.objecta_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple ObjectA Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        context.active_object.location[2] += 1
        return {'FINISHED'}

class ObjectBOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.objectb_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple ObjectB Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        context.active_object.location[2] -= 1
        return {'FINISHED'}

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        if obj == ObjectA:
            row.operator("object.objecta_operator")
        if obj == ObjectB:
            row.operator("object.objectb_operator")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectAOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectBOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectAOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectBOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Try this simple example whether it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: You can simplify this massively by moving the if statement into the operator.

Comment: @timodriaan how exactly? could please provide an example?

Comment: Delete one of both operators and copy the if/else from `draw()` into the other operator's execute method. Then replace the call to the operators inside the if/else with the actual code (`context.active_object.location[2] += 1` e.g.)

Comment: @timodriaan Yes, I agree that in this simple example it makes sense to have less code. But initially I separated into two operator because in the main question it was mentioned "two different buttons each having their own script". And I thought having two operators simplifies understanding of the logic.